# Post request isn't working in node.js express/mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose-schema

I have a route to create a category and when I try to run it in postman it returns an error saying, "Cannot POST /api/category"

I have tried to run through my code again and again but I cannot see where is the problem.
Thank for your help in advance

My schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  categoryName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Categories = mongoose.model("category", CategorySchema);
```

My route:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const Category = require("../../models/Category");



// @route     POST api/category
// @desc      Create or update users category
// @access    Private
router.post(
  "/",
  [auth, [check("categoryName", "Category name is required").not().isEmpty()]],
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(categoryName);
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
  }
);


module.exports = router;
```

[this is the way my code is organized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ext4H.png)

Comment: I don't see any POST route `/api/category` in your code.  Can you show how you add the router to the main express app?

Comment: thanks for reaching out, I have edited my post.

Comment: It should be /api/category instead of / in your route

Comment: Ok, let me try again. Can you show the code from server.js specifically the part where you add the router you export from routes/api/category.js to the main express app? I expect somethig like `app.use('/api/category', ..)`

Comment: Thanks Molda, it was the problem. I wwas missing the route in my server.js file

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Molda I found the problem.

I was missing my route definition in my server.js file.
All good now, thank you for your help.

```js
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

const app = express();

//Connect DB
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("API Running"));

// Define routes
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
app.use("/api/profile", require("./routes/api/profile"));
app.use("/api/category", require("./routes/api/category"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```